# Magento 1.8.1.0 Custom pagination not showing

Tags: pagination, magento-1.8

I have work with Magento 1.8.1.0 Version, for my requirement i create a custom pagination.here the pagination link is not showing. in phtml file i added the line `$this->getPagerHtml()`

```php
    // model intiate
    private function getModel() {
            return Mage::getModel('retailers/retailersmodel');
        }
       // set the collection
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $model = $this->getModel();
            $collection = $model->getCollection();
            $this->setCollection($collection);
        }

         //custom pagination code
        protected function _prepareLayout() {
            parent::_prepareLayout();
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
            $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5 => 5, 10 => 10, 20 => 20, 'all' => 'all'));
            $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCollection()->load();
            return $this;
        }

        public function getPagerHtml() {
            return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
        }
```

thanks for you idea and suggestion.

[image]